# Angular ngModel is not binding to data

Tags: html, angular, forms

Why does two way binding not work?? I am importing the forms module and using the banana syntax. I've also tried reactive forms and that did not work either. It's not populating the input field with the pre-defined value or updating it when the user interacts with this field.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
```

**general.component.ts**

```
  user = {
    firstName: 'john',
  }
```

**general.component.html**

```
  <form>
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        name="firstName"
        id="firstName"
        [(ngModel)]="user.firstName"
      />
  </form>
```

Comment: Working fine . Check this. https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-solomon-w1jpy?file=/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

As i see from your app.module.ts, your general.component.ts does not belong to this module. (in declarations only app.component.ts)

Find module, where you have declarated GeneralComponent, and import there forms module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..., GeneralComponent],
  imports: [..., FormsModule]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. You're correct in analyzing that GeneralComponent does not belong to the main app module. It actually belongs to another feature module. I'm using lazy loading in the app for each of the feature modules and it turns out that you have to import these modules into those feature modules specifically. For some reason I had been trying this for awhile and it wasn't working. Then all of a sudden it started working. Not sure why Angular bugs out like this sometimes. Anyways, I will upvote you because this answer is technically correct with the provided information.